# How to find the difference in values for each entry in one of the columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

What formula could I use to find the Average difference for each time there is an entry for column B.

For example in the excerpt below the average would be 7. We would only use rows 2 and 3 because there is an entry in them. If I can I would like to avoid using VBA.

| Submitted | Returned |
| --- | --- |
| 10/2/2022 |  |
| 10/3/2022 | 10/9/2022 |
| 10/17/2022 | 10/25/2022 |
| 10/25/2022 |  |

10/9/2022 - 10/3/2022 = 6

10/17/2022 - 10/25/2022 = 8

(6 + 8) / 2 = 7

I tried finding a for each function in excel and I tried using `=Average(B-A)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options. Using `AVERAGE`, you can use the following in cell `D1`:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(B2:B5-A2:A5 < 0, "", B2:B5-A2:A5))
```

This function ignores empty values (`""`) as part of the average (but `AVERAGEA` doesn't). The resulting array of `IF` statement will be the difference in days of the **Returned** value and the **Submitted** value if the **Returned** is not empty, otherwise, it will be an empty string. Empty dates are represented in Excel as `0` and any other non-empty date is a positive number, so `B2:B5-A2:A5 < 0` meets our requirement.

Another alternative is to use `SUMPRODUCT` (in cell `D2`):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B5-A2:A5,--(B2:B5>0))/COUNT(B2:B5)
```

**Note**: You cannot use `AVERAGEIF` or `AVERAGEIFS` with the input argument: `B2:B5-A2:A5` because it is not a range and the first input argument is required to be a range.

Here is the output:

[image: sample excel file]